# Fetch Data Table records post selecting Drop down and Keying Text Columns in Data table using R

Tags: r, shiny

How can we get data for data table records post clicking of Update Table action button, post selecting drop down columns and text input from User? Any change in Drop down selection should refresh the Data table records immediately essentially making it as reactive.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(data.table)

shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
  }
  inputs
}

mydata = data.frame(id=letters[1:5], val=sample(10,5,T))
lengthofData <- nrow(mydata)
mydata[["Constraint Type"]] <-  c(shinyInput(inputId = "constraintType",
                                             selectInput,
                                             lengthofData,
                                             "d",
                                             label = "",
                                             choices = c(">", "<")
))

mydata[["Constraint Value"]] <- c(shinyInput(textInput, lengthofData, "t", label = ""))

ui = fluidPage(dataTableOutput("table"),
               actionButton("goButton", "Update Table"),
               dataTableOutput("newtable"))

server = function(input,output){
  output$table <- renderDataTable( df(),server = FALSE,
                                   escape = FALSE,
                                   selection = 'none',
                                   options = list(
                                     sDom  = '<"top">lrt<"bottom">ip',
                                     rowCallback = JS("function(r,d) {$(r).attr('height', '10px')}"),
                                     #columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all")),
                                     scrollY = '50vh',
                                     paging = TRUE,
                                     autoWidth = TRUE
                                   ))
  newTableData <- reactive({
    return(mydata)
  })

  df <- eventReactive(input$goButton, {
    mydata
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  output$newtable <- renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(newTableData(),rownames = FALSE,
                  extensions = c('Responsive', 'Buttons'))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Screen shot for UI
[image: UI screenshot]

Comment: Could you please add a generic description of what you are trying to do here because the constrain value and constrain type seems not very intuitive to solve this case.

Comment: I am trying to capture user input for row level constraint and store the selections to new data table for constructing boxConstraints for Portfolio optimization.

Comment: For example: For row 1 ïf  ">" and 0.8 is selected, then i would have to form constraint as 0 < x < 0.8 . For row 2 if "<" and 0.3 is selected, then i would form constraints as 0.3 < x < 1.   Problem for me is whenever i select the dropdown and provide text input for each row and click on Update Table, i am not able to copy the records with selected values in new data table.